# Does a journal manuscript simultaneously deposited in preprint have more chances to be published after peer-review?

Tags: journals, preprint

As simple question as this: does a preprint have a better chance of being published after peer-review, than a journal article that is not or was not a preprint?

Note that the manuscript was submitted to a call for journal ... and is temporary a preprint

Comment: 'preprint journal' ? Do you mean 'preprint journal article'? Either way this question is far too vague, I doubt that anyone can give you a satisfactory single answer.

Comment: I am very clear in my question though! I am asking something very specific....

Comment: There's no rule that says whether an article is more likely to be accepted if it was a preprint. It depends on the article, the field, the journal, the editor, what the editor had for breakfast...

Comment: hahahaha, ok I got it....

Comment: What is a "preprint journal?"

Comment: A paper submitted to a call for journals...and is temporary a preprint

Comment: @the friend who downvoted my question: What is wrong with my question? I have followed precisely the rules and the instructions of Academia StackExchange on how to ask the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An journal editor once told me about an experiment they did where for every article submitted to their journal during a particular period they tracked if and when the manuscript appeared as a preprint on the arXiv, and what the final fate of those submissions were. In their data they did find manuscripts that appeared on the arxiv before or during peer-review were more likely to be accepted by their journal.

Of course, correlation does not imply causation,  i.e. it is not necessarily true that the simple act of making a preprint available raises the likelihood a particular manuscript gets accepted. More likely this is a selection effect, if authors are confident in their work they are more likely to make it public available as a preprint.

Answer (score 2):

Just about the only effect I can think of making the paper available as a preprint is whether or not reviewers agree to review it. That's because some journals will not show the manuscript to reviewers before they agree to review; they only show the abstract (this is to safeguard the confidentiality of the peer review process). In turn this means if the reviewer might search for a preprint before agreeing to review the paper. Which should have no impact on whether the paper is ultimately accepted.

So: no.